# How to get pipenv running in docker?

Tags: docker, pipenv

Im installing pipenv in my docker:

```
RUN pip install pipenv
RUN cd /my/app/path/ && pipenv install
RUN cd /my/app/path/ && pipenv shell
```

Im getting the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/pipenv", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(cli())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pipenv/vendor/click/core.py", line 722, in __call__
    return self.main(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pipenv/vendor/click/core.py", line 697, in main
    rv = self.invoke(ctx)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pipenv/vendor/click/core.py", line 1066, in invoke
    return _process_result(sub_ctx.command.invoke(sub_ctx))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pipenv/vendor/click/core.py", line 895, in invoke
    return ctx.invoke(self.callback, **ctx.params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pipenv/vendor/click/core.py", line 535, in invoke
    return callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pipenv/cli.py", line 2057, in shell
    do_shell(three=three, python=python, fancy=fancy, shell_args=shell_args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pipenv/cli.py", line 1952, in do_shell
    shell = os.path.abspath(PIPENV_SHELL)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/posixpath.py", line 360, in abspath
    if not isabs(path):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/posixpath.py", line 54, in isabs
    return s.startswith('/')
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'startswith'
```

If I run

```
RUN cd /my/app/path/ && pipenv install --system
```

instead, im getting another error:

```
build   30-Sep-2017 16:50:45    Step 5/9 : RUN cd /my/app/path &&     pipenv install --system
build   30-Sep-2017 16:50:45     ---> Running in cffd31633074
build   30-Sep-2017 16:50:46    [91mPipfile.lock not found, creatingâ€¦
build   30-Sep-2017 16:50:46    [0m[91mLocking [dev-packages] dependenciesâ€¦
build   30-Sep-2017 16:50:46    [0m[91mLocking [packages] dependenciesâ€¦
build   30-Sep-2017 16:50:49    [0m[91mCRITICAL:pip.utils:Error [Errno 2] No such file or directory while executing command python setup.py egg_info
build   30-Sep-2017 16:50:49    [0m[91mTraceback (most recent call last):
build   30-Sep-2017 16:50:49      File "/usr/local/bin/pipenv", line 11, in <module>
build   30-Sep-2017 16:50:49        sys.exit(cli())
build   30-Sep-2017 16:50:49      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pipenv/vendor/click/core.py", line 722, in __call__
build   30-Sep-2017 16:50:49    [0m[91m    return self.main(*args, **kwargs)
build   30-Sep-2017 16:50:49      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pipenv/vendor/click/core.py", line 697, in main
build   30-Sep-2017 16:50:49    [0m[91m    rv = self.invoke(ctx)
build   30-Sep-2017 16:50:49      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pipenv/vendor/click/core.py", line 1066, in invoke
build   30-Sep-2017 16:50:49    [0m[91m    return _process_result(sub_ctx.command.invoke(sub_ctx))
build   30-Sep-2017 16:50:49      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pipenv/vendor/click/core.py", line 895, in invoke
build   30-Sep-2017 16:50:49    [0m[91m    return ctx.invoke(self.callback, **ctx.params)
build   30-Sep-2017 16:50:49      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pipenv/vendor/click/core.py", line 535, in invoke
build   30-Sep-2017 16:50:49        return callback(*args, **kwargs)
build   30-Sep-2017 16:50:49      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pipenv/cli.py", line 1782, in install
build   30-Sep-2017 16:50:49    [0m[91m    do_init(dev=dev, allow_global=system, ignore_pipfile=ignore_pipfile, system=system, skip_lock=skip_lock, verbose=verbose, concurrent=concurrent, deploy=deploy)
build   30-Sep-2017 16:50:49      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pipenv/cli.py", line 1290, in do_init
build   30-Sep-2017 16:50:49    [0m[91m    do_lock(system=system)
build   30-Sep-2017 16:50:49      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pipenv/cli.py", line 1080, in do_lock
build   30-Sep-2017 16:50:49    [0m[91m    pre=pre
build   30-Sep-2017 16:50:49      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pipenv/utils.py", line 421, in resolve_deps
build   30-Sep-2017 16:50:49    [0m[91m    resolved_tree.update(resolver.resolve())
build   30-Sep-2017 16:50:49      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pipenv/patched/piptools/resolver.py", line 101, in resolve
build   30-Sep-2017 16:50:49    [0m[91m    has_changed, best_matches = self._resolve_one_round()
build   30-Sep-2017 16:50:49      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pipenv/patched/piptools/resolver.py", line 199, in _resolve_one_round
build   30-Sep-2017 16:50:49    [0m[91m    for dep in self._iter_dependencies(best_match):
build   30-Sep-2017 16:50:49      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pipenv/patched/piptools/resolver.py", line 293, in _iter_dependencies
build   30-Sep-2017 16:50:49        dependencies = self.repository.get_dependencies(ireq)
build   30-Sep-2017 16:50:49      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pipenv/patched/piptools/repositories/pypi.py", line 171, in get_dependencies
build   30-Sep-2017 16:50:49        result = reqset._prepare_file(self.finder, ireq)
build   30-Sep-2017 16:50:49      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pipenv/patched/pip/req/req_set.py", line 639, in _prepare_file
build   30-Sep-2017 16:50:49    [0m[91m    abstract_dist.prep_for_dist()
build   30-Sep-2017 16:50:49      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pipenv/patched/pip/req/req_set.py", line 134, in prep_for_dist
build   30-Sep-2017 16:50:49    [0m[91m    self.req_to_install.run_egg_info()
build   30-Sep-2017 16:50:49      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pipenv/patched/pip/req/req_install.py", line 438, in run_egg_info
build   30-Sep-2017 16:50:49    [0m[91m    command_desc='python setup.py egg_info')
build   30-Sep-2017 16:50:49      File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pipenv/patched/pip/utils/__init__.py", line 667, in call_subprocess
build   30-Sep-2017 16:50:49    [0m[91m    cwd=cwd, env=env)
build   30-Sep-2017 16:50:49      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 711, in __init__
build   30-Sep-2017 16:50:49    [0m[91m    errread, errwrite)
build   30-Sep-2017 16:50:49      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1343, in _execute_child
build   30-Sep-2017 16:50:49    [0m[91m    raise child_exception
build   30-Sep-2017 16:50:49    OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
error   30-Sep-2017 16:50:49    The command '/bin/sh -c cd /opt/supercrunch/function-service/lib &&     pipenv install --system' returned a non-zero code: 1
build   30-Sep-2017 16:50:49    [0mSending build context to Docker daemon 40.96 kB
```

But when I instead do the following:

```
RUN pip install pipenv
RUN cd /my/app/path && pipenv install
RUN cd /my/app/path && pipenv install --system
```

It is working...

So two question: First: Why is `pipenv shell` giving me this error and Second: Why do I have to do `pipenv install` before `pipenv install --system` to get it working?

I would like to use pipenv to create virtual environments with different python versions and differne dependency versions.

Comment: Seems like an issue, it doesn't even run in a interactive shell. So it won't run in your Dockerfile because you can't get a shell when running a RUN command, they are all run without a TTY. But even getting a shell by running the container doesn't work, so you should open a issue with the pipenv team

Answer (score 175, accepted):

Considering your problem, as I know it the easiest way is to update to the latest version of `pipenv`. It is still in development, so problems are fixed very soon.

We are using `pipenv` with `docker` in production. And we really like it.
There are several things to keep in mind:

1. You need to use `--system` flag, so it will install all packages into the system python, and not into the `virtualenv`. Since `docker` containers do not need to have `virtualenv`s
2. You need to use `--deploy` flag, so your build will fail if your `Pipfile.lock` is out of date
3. You need to use `--ignore-pipfile`, so it won't mess with our setup

Check [the official docs](https://pipenv.kennethreitz.org/en/latest/basics/#pipenv-install) to be sure that this information is up-to-date.

All in all:

```
pipenv install --system --deploy --ignore-pipfile
```

There's also one more thing. If you are using the same `Dockerfile` for both development and production it would be very nice to also use `--dev` flag for the development environment only.

Also, check out our `django` project template to see the full example: [wemake-django-template](https://github.com/wemake-services/wemake-django-template/blob/7882bcf89ad10d88f6624fc1d9b9ab7822175f0a/%7B%7Bcookiecutter.project_name%7D%7D/docker/django/Dockerfile)

Comment: I would love to see how you guys are able to get this working.  I have tried to do pipenv install with all given parameters and it always fails with similar errors

Comment: @Bagelstein so, checkout our template: https://github.com/wemake-services/wemake-django-template But, please not that there is a opened bug in pipenv right now: https://github.com/wemake-services/wemake-django-template/issues/287

Comment: When I use --system I get the following error: __main__.py: error: the following arguments are required: envname

Comment: Please take this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/55610857/2832282 into account ! The official recommendation is to no longer use the `--system` flag for good reasons !

Comment: not a solution `ENTRYPOINT ["pipenv", "shell"]` still not working

Comment: @bm13kk you're not supposed to need that command since the dependencies were installed into system python

Comment: @cryanbhu but i still need it. At least it uploaded .env to environment variables.

Comment: I agree that this answer only circumnavigates the problem. Running `pipenv` means you want to make use of `pipenv run ...` commands (which still fails), not that you just want to install packages (because being in a docker container, you could install packages anyway). You aren't in fact "running pipenv" as the question title requires.

Comment: Does `--ignore-pipfile` have any impact when used in conjuction with `--deploy`?

Answer (score 77):

The pipenv documentation no longer officially recommends using the `--system` flag in docker instances.  Instead, they suggest using virtual environments, as "it is for deployment onto a full-fledged OS".  This is with the caveat:

> ...most containers are deployed without virtualenvs as I believe you both note, I believe the purpose is to stay slim and reduce attack surface area by installing as little as possible

As stated in https://github.com/pypa/pipenv/pull/2762.

Instead, the solution would be to run (as stated in a different answer here):

`RUN pipenv install --deploy --ignore-pipfile`

And then prefix all calls to python with `pipenv run`, e.g. `CMD ["pipenv", "run", "python", "hello.py"]`

Ps. I would have wanted to put this as a comment to the accepted answer, but I don't have the reputation.

Comment: What about if one wants to run gunicorn? how should it be running in CMD or compose command?

Comment: @oyeyipo If anyone is still wondering you can run gunicorn with pipenv, like so 
`CMD ["pipenv", "run", "gunicorn", "main:app", "--reload", "-b", "0.0.0.0:8080"]`

Answer (score 16):

The direct answer to this question is to not use `shell`, but rather `run`:

```
CMD ["pipenv", "run", "python", "my/app.py"]
```

If you need more flexibility, you could also `pipenv run sh init.sh`, which would create a shell initialized with all the `pipenv` environment variables.

I actually prefer the approach [C. Sweet](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47951166/1944335) mentions. If you can get away with prebuilding your virtual environment and simply copying it over (setting `PIPENV_VENV_IN_PROJECT` then using a nested `FROM` followed by `COPY --from=builder-image`), you don't need `python` nor `pipenv` nor `pipenv` dependencies in your final container. This *greatly* reduces the size of the final image.

`Dockerfile`:

```
WORKDIR /etc/service/
CMD ["sh", "/etc/service/init.sh"]
```

`init.sh`:

```
source /etc/service/my/.venv/bin/activate
python my/app.py
```

Comment: "you don't need `python`" - sorry, how would you avoid including python in the container, when deploying a python application?

Answer (score 11):

I just generate a `requirements.txt` file and run it with normal `pip`.

```bash
RUN  pip install pipenv  \
    && pipenv requirements > requirements.txt \
    && pip install -r requirements.txt
```

You can even skip installing `pipenv` in your Dockerfile by generating a requirements file before building the container.

Since this doesn't install dependencies in a `pipenv`-managed virtual environment, there's no need to worry about `pipenv` in the `docker-compose` command.

```yaml
command: >
    - sh 
    - -c 
    - |
      python myscript.py
      python myapp.py
```

[This Python⇒Speed article](https://pythonspeed.com/articles/pipenv-docker/) helped me, which also includes requirements file generation for `poetry` and `pip-tools`.

---

### Previous version, before 2022-04

The `requirements.txt` generation used to be be part of `pipenv lock`. If you're stuck on an old version, use this. But otherwise, just upgrade.

```bash
RUN  pip install pipenv  \
    && pipenv lock --keep-outdated --requirements > requirements.txt \
    && pip install -r requirements.txt
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your solution! I tried it, but it failed with the error `Error: No such option: --requirements`. This is caused bcs pipenv removed the `-r || --requirements` flags & provided a dedicated command for it --> `pipenv requirements`. Be careful, this just prints the requirements to stdout, to create a requirements.txt file shell output redirection is required --> `pipenv requirements > requirements.txt`. For the exact version when it got removed I was too lazy (sorry) but here is the link to the related [doc](https://pipenv.pypa.io/en/latest/advanced/#generating-a-requirements-txt)

Answer (score 1):

The best thing is not to use pipenv directly, as you usually don't need a virtualenv in your container.

There is a tool called micropipenv that you can use in your container instead of pipenv.

https://github.com/thoth-station/micropipenv

## micropipenv use cases

Why should I use `micropipenv` instead of `Pipenv`
or `Poetry`?

- I would like to have a tool that "rules them all" - one lightweight tool to
  support all Python dependency lock file managers (pip-tools, Poetry, Pipenv)
  and lets users decide what they want to use when deploying Python applications
  in containerized environments (e.g. Kubernetes, OpenShift, ...).
- I would like to have a fast and minimalistic tool to install software
  packages in CI.
- I would like to have containerized Python applications as small as possible
  with minimum software shipped and required to build and run the Python
  application in production.
- I would like to convert files produced by Pipenv/Poetry to a pip-tools
  compatible output.
- I don't want to install Pipenv/Poetry, but I would like to run a project that
  uses Pipenv/Poetry for dependency management (e.g. restricted environments).
- My Pipenv installation is broken and `Pipenv upstream did not issue any new Pipenv release <https://github.com/pypa/pipenv/issues/4058>`_.
- I would like to deploy my application into a production environment and my
  application dependencies are managed by Pipenv/Poetry (dependencies are
  already resolved), but I don't want to run Pipenv/Poetry in production (e.g.
  OpenShift's s2i build process).

Answer (score 1):

Each `RUN` directive spawns a new shell so it is useless to try to alter it with a `pipenv shell` command: any following instruction will not benefit from that.

All `RUN` directive that are meant to use pipenv's environment must be prefixed with `pipenv run`.

This would also apply to the `CMD` directive, as well as any command run with a container once the image is built, but you can hack an `ENTRYPOINT` to save prefixes for commands!

```
FROM python
RUN pip install pipenv
WORKDIR /app/
COPY Pipfile* /app
RUN mkdir /app/.venv
RUN pipenv install --deploy
RUN pipenv run something
ENTRYPOINT ["python", "-m", "pipenv", "run"]
CMD ["something"]
```