# Django, Docker, and Pipenv - Error adding new packages

Tags: django, docker, docker-compose, pipenv

Using Pipenv with Docker is causing some issues in my Django project.

I've installed Django locally with Pipenv which generates a `Pipfile` and `Pipfile.lock`. Then used `startproject` to start a new Django project.

Then I add a `Dockerfile` file.

```
# Dockerfile
FROM python:3.7-slim

ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

WORKDIR /code
COPY . /code

RUN pip install pipenv
RUN pipenv install --system
```

And a `docker-compose.yml` file.

```
# docker-compose.yml
version: '3'

services:
  web:
    build: .
    command: python /code/manage.py migrate --noinput && /code/manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    volumes:
      - .:/code
    ports:
      - 8000:8000
```

And run `docker-compose up --build` to build the image and start the container. Everything works.

Now here's the issue...I want to add a new package, let's say `psycopg2` so I can use PostgreSQL.

So...update my `docker-compose.yml` to add PostgreSQL.

```
# docker-compose.yml
version: '3'

services:
  db:
    image: postgres
    volumes:
      - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data/
  web:
    build: .
    command: python /code/manage.py migrate --noinput && /code/manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    volumes:
      - .:/code
    ports:
      - 8000:8000
    depends_on:
      - db

volumes: postgres_data:
```

And update the `DATABASE` config in `settings.py`.

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME': 'postgres',
        'USER': 'postgres',
        'HOST': 'db',
        'PORT': 5432
    }
}
```

Now if I install `psycopg2-binary` locally like `pipenv install psycopg2-binary` this "should" sync with Docker. But I get "No module named 'psycopg2'` errors".

Ok so maybe I need to install it directly within Docker:

```
$ docker-compose exec web pipenv install psycopg2-binary`
```

Nope, same error.

Maybe I need to generate the lock file within Docker?

```
$ docker-compose exec web pipenv lock
```

Again no. So the issue is the state of Pipenv...I feel like I'm close but just not quite grasping something here.

Anyone see the error?

Comment: did you run `docker-compose exec web pipenv install psycopg2-binary` to install the package and `docker-compose up` to start?

Comment: Yes and then `docker-compose up`, no build needed. Still same error which is very strange to me.

Comment: Did you try to install psycopg2-binary in your Dockerfile and then rebuild with `docker-compose build web`?

Comment: Yes, but that didn't work for me either sadly. I think the issue is around not rebuilding the image when there is a local code change, like a new software package. Still trying to find the elegant solution...

Comment: try using `pipenv install --system --deploy --ignore-pipfile` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46503947/how-to-get-pipenv-running-in-docker

Comment: Thanks for that link. I've tried that too...same issues. I'm pretty sure the issue is related to the image: https://docs.docker.com/storage/storagedriver/#images-and-layers. Specifically image layers where the container layer is writable but the image is not. So running a command in the container won't persist on the base image. I can toss everything and rebuild the image from scratch which works but as to updates...I'm still figuring out the elegant approach.

Comment: In other words, with `volumes` in the `docker-compose.yml` filesystem changes sync between local and Docker. Adding a new software package needs to update the image. If I install it in Docker via a command that change will not persist. It will be in the container layer. The trick is to update the underlying image...so could add the software package to `Dockerfile` or could toss underlying image and start from scratch which "would" rebuild entire image including desired software package. Is there a way to do this without wiping entire initial image?

Comment: Why do not you want to rebuild the image?
Here is Docker best practices list https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/dockerfile_best-practices where you can find ways to
optimize your Docker build process like multi-staging. However, your project is not big enough for optimization and it is easier to rebuild the image using command `docker-compose up --force-recreate`
and let Docker manage it.

Comment: Cool let me check that out! I think the fear was around nuking the database (stored in the container) inadvertently, not necessarily the image.

Comment: one way is, you can add package to requirements.txt and run this command
`docker-compose up --build`