# could not install the packages using pipenv when using docker

Tags: python, django, docker, cookiecutter-django

I am setting up a project using `cookiecutter-django` with pipenv instead. I am trying to use docker however I am getting the error as `ERROR: Service 'django' failed to build: The command '/bin/sh -c pipenv install' returned a non-zero code: 1`.

To run the docker i used the following command

```
docker-compose -f local.yml up -d
```

Here is my docker file

local.yml

```
version: '3'

volumes:
  local_postgres_data: {}
  local_postgres_data_backups: {}

services:
  django: &django
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./compose/local/django/Dockerfile
    image: tryavel_local_django
    depends_on:
      - postgres
      - mailhog
    volumes:
      - .:/app
    env_file:
      - ./.envs/.local/.django
      - ./.envs/.local/.postgres
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    command: /start

  postgres:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./compose/production/postgres/Dockerfile
    image: tryavel_production_postgres
    volumes:
      - local_postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
      - local_postgres_data_backups:/backups
    env_file:
      - ./.envs/.local/.postgres

  mailhog:
    image: mailhog/mailhog:v1.0.0
    ports:
      - "8025:8025"

  redis:
    image: redis:5.0

  celeryworker:
    <<: *django
    image: tryavel_local_celeryworker
    depends_on:
      - redis
      - postgres
      - mailhog
    ports: []
    command: /start-celeryworker

  celerybeat:
    <<: *django
    image: tryavel_local_celerybeat
    depends_on:
      - redis
      - postgres
      - mailhog
    ports: []
    command: /start-celerybeat

  flower:
    <<: *django
    image: tryavel_local_flower
    ports:
      - "5555:5555"
    command: /start-flower
```

compose/local/django/Dockerfile

```
FROM python:3.7-alpine

ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

RUN apk update \
  # psycopg2 dependencies
  && apk add --virtual build-deps gcc python3-dev musl-dev \
  && apk add postgresql-dev \
  # Pillow dependencies
  && apk add jpeg-dev zlib-dev freetype-dev lcms2-dev openjpeg-dev tiff-dev tk-dev tcl-dev \
  # CFFI dependencies
  && apk add libffi-dev py-cffi \
  # Translations dependencies
  && apk add gettext \
  # https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/django-admin/#dbshell
  && apk add postgresql-client

# Requirements are installed here to ensure they will be cached.
RUN pip3 install --upgrade pip
RUN pip3 install pipenv
COPY Pipfile* /app/
RUN pipenv install
# COPY ./requirements /requirements
# RUN pip install -r /requirements/local.txt

COPY ./compose/production/django/entrypoint /entrypoint
RUN sed -i 's/\r$//g' /entrypoint
RUN chmod +x /entrypoint

COPY ./compose/local/django/start /start
RUN sed -i 's/\r$//g' /start
RUN chmod +x /start

COPY ./compose/local/django/celery/worker/start /start-celeryworker
RUN sed -i 's/\r$//g' /start-celeryworker
RUN chmod +x /start-celeryworker

COPY ./compose/local/django/celery/beat/start /start-celerybeat
RUN sed -i 's/\r$//g' /start-celerybeat
RUN chmod +x /start-celerybeat

COPY ./compose/local/django/celery/flower/start /start-flower
RUN sed -i 's/\r$//g' /start-flower
RUN chmod +x /start-flower

WORKDIR /app

ENTRYPOINT ["/entrypoint"]
```

why am i getting pipenv issue?

error

```
Step 7/24 : RUN pipenv install
 ---> Running in bc10595bd5d2
Creating a virtualenv for this project?
Pipfile: /Pipfile
Using /usr/local/bin/python (3.7.3) to create virtualenv?
? Creating virtual environment...Already using interpreter /usr/local/bin/python
Using base prefix '/usr/local'
New python executable in /root/.local/share/virtualenvs/-x-v5uFv0/bin/python
Installing setuptools, pip, wheel...
done.

? Successfully created virtual environment! 
Virtualenv location: /root/.local/share/virtualenvs/-x-v5uFv0
Creating a Pipfile for this project?
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/pipenv", line 10, in <module>
    sys.exit(cli())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pipenv/vendor/click/core.py", line 764, in __call__
    return self.main(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pipenv/vendor/click/core.py", line 717, in main
    rv = self.invoke(ctx)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pipenv/vendor/click/core.py", line 1137, in invoke
    return _process_result(sub_ctx.command.invoke(sub_ctx))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pipenv/vendor/click/core.py", line 956, in invoke
    return ctx.invoke(self.callback, **ctx.params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pipenv/vendor/click/core.py", line 555, in invoke
    return callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pipenv/vendor/click/decorators.py", line 64, in new_func
    return ctx.invoke(f, obj, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pipenv/vendor/click/core.py", line 555, in invoke
    return callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pipenv/vendor/click/decorators.py", line 17, in new_func
    return f(get_current_context(), *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pipenv/cli/command.py", line 254, in install
    editable_packages=state.installstate.editables,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pipenv/core.py", line 1741, in do_install
    pypi_mirror=pypi_mirror,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pipenv/core.py", line 609, in ensure_project
    validate=validate, skip_requirements=skip_requirements, system=system
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pipenv/core.py", line 320, in ensure_pipfile
    project.create_pipfile(python=python)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pipenv/project.py", line 697, in create_pipfile
    config_parser = ConfigOptionParser(name=self.name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pipenv/patched/notpip/_internal/cli/parser.py", line 142, in __init__
    assert self.name
AssertionError
ERROR: Service 'django' failed to build: The command '/bin/sh -c pipenv install' returned a non-zero code: 1
Failed to deploy 'Compose: local.yml': `docker-compose` process finished with exit code 1
```

when i instead use the command `pipenv install --system` i get following error

```
Step 7/24 : RUN pipenv install  --system
 ---> Running in b35f2bb70207
[pipenv.exceptions.PipenvOptionsError]:   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pipenv/vendor/click/decorators.py", line 17, in new_func
[pipenv.exceptions.PipenvOptionsError]:       return f(get_current_context(), *args, **kwargs)
[pipenv.exceptions.PipenvOptionsError]:   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pipenv/cli/command.py", line 254, in install
[pipenv.exceptions.PipenvOptionsError]:       editable_packages=state.installstate.editables,
[pipenv.exceptions.PipenvOptionsError]:   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pipenv/core.py", line 1741, in do_install
[pipenv.exceptions.PipenvOptionsError]:       pypi_mirror=pypi_mirror,
[pipenv.exceptions.PipenvOptionsError]:   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pipenv/core.py", line 609, in ensure_project
[pipenv.exceptions.PipenvOptionsError]:       validate=validate, skip_requirements=skip_requirements, system=system
[pipenv.exceptions.PipenvOptionsError]:   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pipenv/core.py", line 282, in ensure_pipfile
[pipenv.exceptions.PipenvOptionsError]:       "--system is intended to be used for pre-existing Pipfile
ERROR:: --system is intended to be used for pre-existing Pipfile installation, not installation of specific packages. Aborting.
```

Comment: “Returned exit code 1” is just Linux-speak for “it didn’t work”.  The actual error message is going to be in the couple dozen lines before that.

Comment: @DavidMaze updated with error screenshot.

Comment: Please don’t paste screenshots of terminal windows into SO questions.  Paste the actual text of the error message instead.

Comment: I have pasted the actual text

Comment: This works for me https://stackoverflow.com/a/49705601/5341872

Answer (score 3):

You need just cd to /app in Dockerfile

```
# Requirements are installed here to ensure they will be cached.
RUN pip3 install --upgrade pip
RUN pip3 install pipenv
COPY Pipfile* /app/
RUN cd /app && pipenv install
```

Answer (score 1):

When you use --system. Pipfile.lock is required. Ensure you are copying pipfile.lock to the correct dir