# Dockerfile Build Fails - Pipenv and Pyenv Multiple Versions of Python Found

Tags: python-3.x, docker, dockerfile, pipenv, pyenv

**Question: How can I fix the Dockerfile to properly freeze requirements.txt and successfully build?**

I am working through deploying a Dockerfile of a Python script utilizing Pyenv and Pipenv for local development.

On the build step where the Piplock file is frozen to requirements.txt, I receive the following error:

> Error: Invalid value for "--python": Expected Python at path
>   /Users/jz/.local/share/virtualenvs/quanter-TP0oWHoL/bin/python3 does
>   not exist

My Dockerfile is:

```
FROM python:3.7
RUN pip install pipenv
COPY Pipfile* /tmp/
RUN cd /tmp && pipenv --python /Users/x/.local/share/virtualenvs/quanter-TP0oWHoL/bin/python3 lock --requirements > requirements.txt
ENV RDKAFKA_INSTALL=system
RUN pip install -r /tmp/requirements.txt
COPY . /tmp/app/
RUN pip install /tmp/app/
CMD ["python", "./tmp/app/main.py"]
```

Creation of the local Pipenv environment provided this information about the interpreter, (which was used in the Dockerfile):

> Using /usr/local/opt/pyenv/versions/3.8.0/bin/python3 (3.8.0) to
>   create virtualenv… ⠙ Creating virtual environment...Using base prefix
>   '/usr/local/opt/pyenv/versions/3.8.0' New python executable in
>   /Users/x/.local/share/virtualenvs/quanter-TP0oWHoL/bin/python3 Also
>   creating executable in
>   /Users/x/.local/share/virtualenvs/quanter-TP0oWHoL/bin/python

Pyenv is using 3.8.0 locally:

```
pyenv versions
system
3.7.5
* 3.8.0 (set by /Users/x/Projects/quanter/.python-version)
```

Any help getting this working would be greatly appreciated! Thank you.

Comment: Why do you need manually creating lock: converting requirement from pipenv and making a lock of it? Pipenv does this for you, isn't?

Comment: @funnydman While I want to use Pipenv for its virtual environment in local development, I don’t want a virtual environment inside of the Docker environment, thus confusing the purpose of Docker being the environment. I just want to use Pip in the Docker container and install the dependencies systemically from a requirements file. no virtual environment needed.

Comment: @funnydman as it stands right now Pipenv doesn’t work anyways due to the issue I’ve outlined with not being able to locate the Pyenv interpreter.

Answer (score 0):

The original error came from the idea that `pipenv` can not find python executable on the given path. It is hardcoded, but on every fully new build, `pipenv` will create env with a different name. Take a look at this interesting discussion: [How does pipenv know the virtualenv for the current project?](https://github.com/pypa/pipenv/issues/796#issuecomment-333372544), it seems like it could be predictable, but there should be a better solution.

Firstly, you do not need to specify a path to python executable directly because python image comes only with one system python installation, e.g. it will be available by default via `python` (of course you can create different environments with different versions of python by hand).

Secondly, you can handle `pipenv` in docker env in a more [nicer and preferable way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46503947/how-to-get-pipenv-running-in-docker/55610857#55610857), instead of converting `pipenv` into pip like flow. Take a look at the example below:

```
FROM python:3.7

COPY Pipfile /
COPY Pipfile.lock /

RUN pip3 install pipenv \
    && pipenv install --system --deploy --ignore-pipfile
```

Several notes worthing to consider:

1. **Commit `Pipfile.lock` into VCS**. In this case, you can be sure that in every environment you have exactly the same versions of packages and its dependencies.
2. **You may be interested in `--system` option**. That says to install dependencies into a system instead of `virtualenv` (this is what you expect). But according to this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55610857/9926721 It is not officially recommended. But still, a quite popular project [wemake-django-template](https://github.com/wemake-services/wemake-django-template/blob/7882bcf89ad10d88f6624fc1d9b9ab7822175f0a/%7B%7Bcookiecutter.project_name%7D%7D/docker/django/Dockerfile) uses it as well.
3. **Consider splitting up environments.** There is useful flag `--dev` for it. No more several requirement files. Handle it more efficient way.

Comment: This is sound advice, I'm realizing I was thinking about the local interpreter instead of the interpreter in the Docker image and points for the --system option that allows the dependencies to be installed system-wide. I'll review this evening and post back any questions or mark this answered. Thank you @funnydman.

Comment: @Liquidgenius feel free to ask any questions.