# Make `pipenv run` run multiple commands

Tags: docker, pipenv

I'm using a Docker container for local web development. I have a bash script I use for running Django's `manage.py test`, `flake8`, and `coverage html`, all within a pipenv environment within the Docker container.

A simple version is:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
set -e

docker exec hines_web /bin/sh -c "pipenv run coverage run --source=. manage.py test ; pipenv run flake8 ; pipenv run coverage html"
```

This works. However, because each command has to separately use `pipenv run` it's slower than it needs to be.

Is there a way to either chain several commands together after a single `pipenv run`, or else to send multiple commands into `pipenv shell` for them to be run?

(Any thoughts on improving the general way of doing this appreciated!)

Comment: You should be able to use `pipenv` to set up a non-Docker host-based virtual environment.  That would be generally faster and doesn't require administrator-equivalent permissions to use.

Comment: I’m not 100% sure what you mean. Do you mean run pipenv directly on my Mac rather than in a Docker container? That’s what I’ve been doing previously and now I’m trying to use Docker so that I have a more easily replicable environment, aside from the pipenv aspect.

Comment: Do you need pipenv inside a docker container? you could directly install packages to the docker container `pipenv install --deploy --system` and then normally run `python3 filename.py`

Comment: @Ishan That's a good point, and I started out that way, but I read that using `--system` within Docker images is no longer recommended: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46503947/how-to-get-pipenv-running-in-docker/55610857#55610857

Answer (score 2):

Here's my workaround which is laborious enough to make me think I'm approaching this entirely wrongly, but it works. Three steps:

**1.** A shell script that will run our commands. This is designed to be run *within* the pipenv environment. This is `scripts/pipenv-run-tests.sh`:

```sh
#!/bin/sh
set -e

# Runs the Django test suite, flake8, and generates HTML coverage reports.

# This script is called by using the shortcut defined in Pipfile:
#   pipenv run tests

# You can optionally pass in a test, or test module or class, as an argument, e.g.
# ./pipenv-run-tests.sh tests.appname.test_models.TestClass.test_a_thing
TESTS_TO_RUN=${1:-tests}

coverage run --source=. ./manage.py test $TESTS_TO_RUN
flake8
coverage html
```

**2.** We define a [Custom Script Shortcut](https://pipenv.pypa.io/en/latest/advanced/#custom-script-shortcuts) in our `Pipfile`:

```
[scripts]
tests = "./scripts/pipenv-run-tests.sh"
```

This means that if we log into the shell on the Docker container we could do: `pipenv run tests` and our `scripts/pipenv-run-tests.sh` would be run, within the pipenv environment. Any arguments included after `pipenv run tests` are passed on tot he script.

**3.** Finally we have a script designed to be run from the host machine, that runs our Custom Script Shortcut within Docker. This is `scripts/run-tests.sh`:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
set -e

# Call this from the host machine.
# It will call the `tests` shortcut defined in Pipfile, which will run
# a script within the pipenv environment.

# You can optionally pass in a test, or test module or class, as an argument, e.g.
# ./run-tests.sh tests.appname.test_models.TestClass.test_a_thing
TESTS_TO_RUN=${1:-tests}

docker exec hines_web /bin/sh -c "pipenv run tests $TESTS_TO_RUN"
```

So now, on the host machine, we can do: `./scripts/run-tests.sh` and that will, within the Docker container, call the pipenv shortcut, which will run the `scripts/pipenv-run-tests.sh` script. Any arguments provided are passed on to the final script.

(Note that `hines_web` in the above is the name of my Docker container defined in my `docker-compose.yml`.)