# Docker-compose, django and pipfile.lock - docker can't install packages from pipfile.lock

Tags: python, django, docker, docker-compose

After some searches in the internet, I come to ask for your help.
I would like to create a server with django in the backend and react in the frontend.
Although I do not have any problems with the frontend, I cannot properly initialise the backend with docker-compose.

Here is my docker-compose file :

```
version: "3.9"
services:
  # Frontend and backend
  django_server:
    container_name: has_server_backend
    build: ./server
    depends_on:
      - mongo_db
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    volumes:
      - ./server:/has_server
  frontend:
    container_name: has_server_frontend
    build: ./frontend
    command: npm start
    ports: 
      - "3000:3000"
  
  # Services associated
  mqtt:
    container_name: mqtt_broker
    image: eclipse-mosquitto
    volumes: 
      - ./services/mosquitto/config:/mosquitto/config
      - ./services/mosquitto/data:/mosquitto/data
      - ./services/mosquitto/logs:/mosquitto/logs
  mongo_db:
    container_name: has_server_mongodb
    image: mongo
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - ./services/mongo-db/db:/data/db
    environment:
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: root
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: mongoadmin
      MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE: has_server
    ports:
      - 27017:27017
  mongo-express:
    image: mongo-express
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8081:8081
    environment:
      ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMIN_USERNAME: root
      ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMIN_USERNAME: my_password
```

Here is the docker file for the backend :

```
FROM python:3.8

ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
COPY . has_server/
WORKDIR /has_server
RUN ls -al
RUN pip install pipenv
RUN pipenv install
COPY . ./
EXPOSE 8000

CMD [ "python", "manage.py", "runserver", "0.0.0.0:8000"]
```

Here is my Pipfile.lock:

```
{
"_meta": {
"hash": {
"sha256": "4c26f7511ec3af2303f9a21d47b0a6dc919fcf2a0a32862c85f2e4a23fc694ea"
},
"pipfile-spec": 6,
"requires": {
"python_version": "3.8"
},
"sources": [
{
"name": "pypi",
"url": "https://pypi.python.org/simple",
"verify_ssl": true
}
]
},
"default": {
"asgiref": {
"hashes": [
"sha256:92906c611ce6c967347bbfea733f13d6313901d54dcca88195eaeb52b2a8e8ee",
"sha256:d1216dfbdfb63826470995d31caed36225dcaf34f182e0fa257a4dd9e86f1b78"
],
"version": "==3.3.4"
},
"django": {
"hashes": [
"sha256:642d8eceab321ca743ae71e0f985ff8fdca59f07aab3a9fb362c617d23e33a76",
"sha256:d4666c2edefa38c5ede0ec1655424c56dc47ceb04b6d8d62a7eac09db89545c1"
],
"version": "==3.0.5"
},
"djongo": {
"hashes": [
"sha256:b4b767174095c06eae2c344f201dc809ffc156b9c99d44ab8f798309090cae29"
],
"version": "==1.3.4"
},
"pymongo": {
"hashes": [
"sha256:03be7ad107d252bb7325d4af6309fdd2c025d08854d35f0e7abc8bf048f4245e",
"sha256:071552b065e809d24c5653fcc14968cfd6fde4e279408640d5ac58e3353a3c5f",
"sha256:08b8723248730599c9803ae4c97b8f3f76c55219104303c88cb962a31e3bb5ee",
"sha256:08bda7b2c522ff9f1e554570da16298271ebb0c56ab9699446aacba249008988",
"sha256:0aaf4d44f1f819360f9432df538d54bbf850f18152f34e20337c01b828479171",
"sha256:0cabfc297f4cf921f15bc789a8fbfd7115eb9f813d3f47a74b609894bc66ab0d",
"sha256:13acf6164ead81c9fc2afa0e1ea6d6134352973ce2bb35496834fee057063c04",
"sha256:15b083d1b789b230e5ac284442d9ecb113c93f3785a6824f748befaab803b812",
"sha256:161fcd3281c42f644aa8dec7753cca2af03ce654e17d76da4f0dab34a12480ca",
"sha256:1a994a42f49dab5b6287e499be7d3d2751776486229980d8857ad53b8333d469",
"sha256:20d75ea11527331a2980ab04762a9d960bcfea9475c54bbeab777af880de61cd",
"sha256:225c61e08fe517aede7912937939e09adf086c8e6f7e40d4c85ad678c2c2aea3",
"sha256:3135dd574ef1286189f3f04a36c8b7a256376914f8cbbce66b94f13125ded858",
"sha256:3491c7de09e44eded16824cb58cf9b5cc1dc6f066a0bb7aa69929d02aa53b828",
"sha256:3551912f5c34d8dd7c32c6bb00ae04192af47f7b9f653608f107d19c1a21a194",
"sha256:38a7b5140a48fc91681cdb5cb95b7cd64640b43d19259fdd707fa9d5a715f2b2",
"sha256:3a3498a8326111221560e930f198b495ea6926937e249f475052ffc6893a6680",
"sha256:3bfc7689a1bacb9bcd2f2d5185d99507aa29f667a58dd8adaa43b5a348139e46",
"sha256:421d13523d11c57f57f257152bc4a6bb463aadf7a3918e9c96fefdd6be8dbfb8",
"sha256:424799c71ff435094e5fb823c40eebb4500f0e048133311e9c026467e8ccebac",
"sha256:474e21d0e07cd09679e357d1dac76e570dab86665e79a9d3354b10a279ac6fb3",
"sha256:4c7e8c8e1e1918dcf6a652ac4b9d87164587c26fd2ce5dd81e73a5ab3b3d492f",
"sha256:506a6dab4c7ffdcacdf0b8e70bd20eb2e77fa994519547c9d88d676400fcad58",
"sha256:510cd3bfabb63a07405b7b79fae63127e34c118b7531a2cbbafc7a24fd878594",
"sha256:517ba47ca04a55b1f50ee8df9fd97f6c37df5537d118fb2718952b8623860466",
"sha256:539d4cb1b16b57026999c53e5aab857fe706e70ae5310cc8c232479923f932e6",
"sha256:5c36428cc4f7fae56354db7f46677fd21222fc3cb1e8829549b851172033e043",
"sha256:5db59223ed1e634d842a053325f85f908359c6dac9c8ddce8ef145061fae7df8",
"sha256:5e606846c049ed40940524057bfdf1105af6066688c0e6a1a3ce2038589bae70",
"sha256:6060794aac9f7b0644b299f46a9c6cbc0bc470bd01572f4134df140afd41ded6",
"sha256:62c29bc36a6d9be68fe7b5aaf1e120b4aa66a958d1e146601fcd583eb12cae7b",
"sha256:73326b211e7410c8bd6a74500b1e3f392f39cf10862e243d00937e924f112c01",
"sha256:78f07961f4f214ea8e80be63cffd5cc158eb06cd922ffbf6c7155b11728f28f9",
"sha256:7c97554ea521f898753d9773891d0347ebfaddcc1dee2ad94850b163171bf1f1",
"sha256:8898f6699f740ca93a0879ed07d8e6db02d68af889d0ebb3d13ab017e6b1af1e",
"sha256:8a41fdc751dc4707a4fafb111c442411816a7c225ebb5cadb57599534b5d5372",
"sha256:8e0004b0393d72d76de94b4792a006cb960c1c65c7659930fbf9a81ce4341982",
"sha256:977b1d4f868986b4ba5d03c317fde4d3b66e687d74473130cd598e3103db34fa",
"sha256:9a4f6e0b01df820ba9ed0b4e618ca83a1c089e48d4f268d0e00dcd49893d4549",
"sha256:9b9298964389c180a063a9e8bac8a80ed42de11d04166b20249bfa0a489e0e0f",
"sha256:a08c8b322b671857c81f4c30cd3c8df2895fd3c0e9358714f39e0ef8fb327702",
"sha256:ad31f184dcd3271de26ab1f9c51574afb99e1b0e484ab1da3641256b723e4994",
"sha256:aff3656af2add93f290731a6b8930b23b35c0c09569150130a58192b3ec6fc61",
"sha256:b2f41261b648cf5dee425f37ff14f4ad151c2f24b827052b402637158fd056ef",
"sha256:b413117210fa6d92664c3d860571e8e8727c3e8f2ff197276c5d0cb365abd3ad",
"sha256:b7efc7e7049ef366777cfd35437c18a4166bb50a5606a1c840ee3b9624b54fc9",
"sha256:b8f94acd52e530a38f25e4d5bf7ddfdd4bea9193e718f58419def0d4406b58d3",
"sha256:d0a70151d7de8a3194cdc906bcc1a42e14594787c64b0c1c9c975e5a2af3e251",
"sha256:d360e5d5dd3d55bf5d1776964625018d85b937d1032bae1926dd52253decd0db",
"sha256:d4e62417e89b717a7bcd8576ac3108cd063225942cc91c5b37ff5465fdccd386",
"sha256:d65bac5f6724d9ea6f0b5a0f0e4952fbbf209adcf6b5583b54c54bd2fcd74dc0",
"sha256:e02beaab433fd1104b2804f909e694cfbdb6578020740a9051597adc1cd4e19f",
"sha256:e4b631688dfbdd61b5610e20b64b99d25771c6d52d9da73349342d2a0f11c46a",
"sha256:e4e9db78b71db2b1684ee4ecc3e32c4600f18cdf76e6b9ae03e338e52ee4b168",
"sha256:eb4d176394c37a76e8b0afe54b12d58614a67a60a7f8c0dd3a5afbb013c01092",
"sha256:f08665d3cc5abc2f770f472a9b5f720a9b3ab0b8b3bb97c7c1487515e5653d39",
"sha256:f3d851af3852f16ad4adc7ee054fd9c90a7a5063de94d815b7f6a88477b9f4c6",
"sha256:f4ba58157e8ae33ee86fadf9062c506e535afd904f07f9be32731f4410a23b7f",
"sha256:f664ed7613b8b18f0ce5696b146776266a038c19c5cd6efffa08ecc189b01b73",
"sha256:f947b359cc4769af8b49be7e37af01f05fcf15b401da2528021148e4a54426d1",
"sha256:fe4189846448df013cd9df11bba38ddf78043f8c290a9f06430732a7a8601cce",
"sha256:fea5cb1c63efe1399f0812532c7cf65458d38fd011be350bc5021dfcac39fba8",
"sha256:fedf0dee7a412ca6d1d6d92c158fe9cbaa8ea0cae90d268f9ccc0744de7a97d0",
"sha256:fffff7bfb6799a763d3742c59c6ee7ffadda21abed557637bc44ed1080876484"
],
"version": "==3.11.4"
},
"pytz": {
"hashes": [
"sha256:83a4a90894bf38e243cf052c8b58f381bfe9a7a483f6a9cab140bc7f702ac4da",
"sha256:eb10ce3e7736052ed3623d49975ce333bcd712c7bb19a58b9e2089d4057d0798"
],
"version": "==2021.1"
},
"server": {
"editable": true,
"path": "."
},
"sqlparse": {
"hashes": [
"sha256:ce028444cfab83be538752a2ffdb56bc417b7784ff35bb9a3062413717807dec",
"sha256:d9cf190f51cbb26da0412247dfe4fb5f4098edb73db84e02f9fc21fdca31fed4"
],
"version": "==0.2.4"
}
},
"develop": {
"asgiref": {
"hashes": [
"sha256:92906c611ce6c967347bbfea733f13d6313901d54dcca88195eaeb52b2a8e8ee",
"sha256:d1216dfbdfb63826470995d31caed36225dcaf34f182e0fa257a4dd9e86f1b78"
],
"version": "==3.3.4"
},
"django": {
"hashes": [
"sha256:642d8eceab321ca743ae71e0f985ff8fdca59f07aab3a9fb362c617d23e33a76",
"sha256:d4666c2edefa38c5ede0ec1655424c56dc47ceb04b6d8d62a7eac09db89545c1"
],
"version": "==3.0.5"
},
"djongo": {
"hashes": [
"sha256:b4b767174095c06eae2c344f201dc809ffc156b9c99d44ab8f798309090cae29"
],
"version": "==1.3.4"
},
"e1839a8": {
"editable": true,
"path": "."
},
"pymongo": {
"hashes": [
"sha256:03be7ad107d252bb7325d4af6309fdd2c025d08854d35f0e7abc8bf048f4245e",
"sha256:071552b065e809d24c5653fcc14968cfd6fde4e279408640d5ac58e3353a3c5f",
"sha256:08b8723248730599c9803ae4c97b8f3f76c55219104303c88cb962a31e3bb5ee",
"sha256:08bda7b2c522ff9f1e554570da16298271ebb0c56ab9699446aacba249008988",
"sha256:0aaf4d44f1f819360f9432df538d54bbf850f18152f34e20337c01b828479171",
"sha256:0cabfc297f4cf921f15bc789a8fbfd7115eb9f813d3f47a74b609894bc66ab0d",
"sha256:13acf6164ead81c9fc2afa0e1ea6d6134352973ce2bb35496834fee057063c04",
"sha256:15b083d1b789b230e5ac284442d9ecb113c93f3785a6824f748befaab803b812",
"sha256:161fcd3281c42f644aa8dec7753cca2af03ce654e17d76da4f0dab34a12480ca",
"sha256:1a994a42f49dab5b6287e499be7d3d2751776486229980d8857ad53b8333d469",
"sha256:20d75ea11527331a2980ab04762a9d960bcfea9475c54bbeab777af880de61cd",
"sha256:225c61e08fe517aede7912937939e09adf086c8e6f7e40d4c85ad678c2c2aea3",
"sha256:3135dd574ef1286189f3f04a36c8b7a256376914f8cbbce66b94f13125ded858",
"sha256:3491c7de09e44eded16824cb58cf9b5cc1dc6f066a0bb7aa69929d02aa53b828",
"sha256:3551912f5c34d8dd7c32c6bb00ae04192af47f7b9f653608f107d19c1a21a194",
"sha256:38a7b5140a48fc91681cdb5cb95b7cd64640b43d19259fdd707fa9d5a715f2b2",
"sha256:3a3498a8326111221560e930f198b495ea6926937e249f475052ffc6893a6680",
"sha256:3bfc7689a1bacb9bcd2f2d5185d99507aa29f667a58dd8adaa43b5a348139e46",
"sha256:421d13523d11c57f57f257152bc4a6bb463aadf7a3918e9c96fefdd6be8dbfb8",
"sha256:424799c71ff435094e5fb823c40eebb4500f0e048133311e9c026467e8ccebac",
"sha256:474e21d0e07cd09679e357d1dac76e570dab86665e79a9d3354b10a279ac6fb3",
"sha256:4c7e8c8e1e1918dcf6a652ac4b9d87164587c26fd2ce5dd81e73a5ab3b3d492f",
"sha256:506a6dab4c7ffdcacdf0b8e70bd20eb2e77fa994519547c9d88d676400fcad58",
"sha256:510cd3bfabb63a07405b7b79fae63127e34c118b7531a2cbbafc7a24fd878594",
"sha256:517ba47ca04a55b1f50ee8df9fd97f6c37df5537d118fb2718952b8623860466",
"sha256:539d4cb1b16b57026999c53e5aab857fe706e70ae5310cc8c232479923f932e6",
"sha256:5c36428cc4f7fae56354db7f46677fd21222fc3cb1e8829549b851172033e043",
"sha256:5db59223ed1e634d842a053325f85f908359c6dac9c8ddce8ef145061fae7df8",
"sha256:5e606846c049ed40940524057bfdf1105af6066688c0e6a1a3ce2038589bae70",
"sha256:6060794aac9f7b0644b299f46a9c6cbc0bc470bd01572f4134df140afd41ded6",
"sha256:62c29bc36a6d9be68fe7b5aaf1e120b4aa66a958d1e146601fcd583eb12cae7b",
"sha256:73326b211e7410c8bd6a74500b1e3f392f39cf10862e243d00937e924f112c01",
"sha256:78f07961f4f214ea8e80be63cffd5cc158eb06cd922ffbf6c7155b11728f28f9",
"sha256:7c97554ea521f898753d9773891d0347ebfaddcc1dee2ad94850b163171bf1f1",
"sha256:8898f6699f740ca93a0879ed07d8e6db02d68af889d0ebb3d13ab017e6b1af1e",
"sha256:8a41fdc751dc4707a4fafb111c442411816a7c225ebb5cadb57599534b5d5372",
"sha256:8e0004b0393d72d76de94b4792a006cb960c1c65c7659930fbf9a81ce4341982",
"sha256:977b1d4f868986b4ba5d03c317fde4d3b66e687d74473130cd598e3103db34fa",
"sha256:9a4f6e0b01df820ba9ed0b4e618ca83a1c089e48d4f268d0e00dcd49893d4549",
"sha256:9b9298964389c180a063a9e8bac8a80ed42de11d04166b20249bfa0a489e0e0f",
"sha256:a08c8b322b671857c81f4c30cd3c8df2895fd3c0e9358714f39e0ef8fb327702",
"sha256:ad31f184dcd3271de26ab1f9c51574afb99e1b0e484ab1da3641256b723e4994",
"sha256:aff3656af2add93f290731a6b8930b23b35c0c09569150130a58192b3ec6fc61",
"sha256:b2f41261b648cf5dee425f37ff14f4ad151c2f24b827052b402637158fd056ef",
"sha256:b413117210fa6d92664c3d860571e8e8727c3e8f2ff197276c5d0cb365abd3ad",
"sha256:b7efc7e7049ef366777cfd35437c18a4166bb50a5606a1c840ee3b9624b54fc9",
"sha256:b8f94acd52e530a38f25e4d5bf7ddfdd4bea9193e718f58419def0d4406b58d3",
"sha256:d0a70151d7de8a3194cdc906bcc1a42e14594787c64b0c1c9c975e5a2af3e251",
"sha256:d360e5d5dd3d55bf5d1776964625018d85b937d1032bae1926dd52253decd0db",
"sha256:d4e62417e89b717a7bcd8576ac3108cd063225942cc91c5b37ff5465fdccd386",
"sha256:d65bac5f6724d9ea6f0b5a0f0e4952fbbf209adcf6b5583b54c54bd2fcd74dc0",
"sha256:e02beaab433fd1104b2804f909e694cfbdb6578020740a9051597adc1cd4e19f",
"sha256:e4b631688dfbdd61b5610e20b64b99d25771c6d52d9da73349342d2a0f11c46a",
"sha256:e4e9db78b71db2b1684ee4ecc3e32c4600f18cdf76e6b9ae03e338e52ee4b168",
"sha256:eb4d176394c37a76e8b0afe54b12d58614a67a60a7f8c0dd3a5afbb013c01092",
"sha256:f08665d3cc5abc2f770f472a9b5f720a9b3ab0b8b3bb97c7c1487515e5653d39",
"sha256:f3d851af3852f16ad4adc7ee054fd9c90a7a5063de94d815b7f6a88477b9f4c6",
"sha256:f4ba58157e8ae33ee86fadf9062c506e535afd904f07f9be32731f4410a23b7f",
"sha256:f664ed7613b8b18f0ce5696b146776266a038c19c5cd6efffa08ecc189b01b73",
"sha256:f947b359cc4769af8b49be7e37af01f05fcf15b401da2528021148e4a54426d1",
"sha256:fe4189846448df013cd9df11bba38ddf78043f8c290a9f06430732a7a8601cce",
"sha256:fea5cb1c63efe1399f0812532c7cf65458d38fd011be350bc5021dfcac39fba8",
"sha256:fedf0dee7a412ca6d1d6d92c158fe9cbaa8ea0cae90d268f9ccc0744de7a97d0",
"sha256:fffff7bfb6799a763d3742c59c6ee7ffadda21abed557637bc44ed1080876484"
],
"version": "==3.11.4"
},
"pytz": {
"hashes": [
"sha256:83a4a90894bf38e243cf052c8b58f381bfe9a7a483f6a9cab140bc7f702ac4da",
"sha256:eb10ce3e7736052ed3623d49975ce333bcd712c7bb19a58b9e2089d4057d0798"
],
"version": "==2021.1"
},
"sqlparse": {
"hashes": [
"sha256:ce028444cfab83be538752a2ffdb56bc417b7784ff35bb9a3062413717807dec",
"sha256:d9cf190f51cbb26da0412247dfe4fb5f4098edb73db84e02f9fc21fdca31fed4"
],
"version": "==0.2.4"
}
}
}
```

When I try to look for the docker logs for the backend I get this kind of error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "manage.py", line 11, in main
from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "manage.py", line 22, in
main()
File "manage.py", line 13, in main
raise ImportError(
ImportError: Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you forget to activate a virtual environment?
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: (Without Docker, does running the exact set of commands in the Dockerfile work?  I'd expect `pipenv install` to create a virtual environment normally, but then normal `python` wouldn't be able to see that.  See also [How to get pipenv running in docker?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46503947/how-to-get-pipenv-running-in-docker))

Comment: When I try to run django without docker it works without any problem. I realized when I try to use the command pip freeze the dependencies found in the pipfile.lock are not installed in the docker container. I will try to activate pipenv in the docker container and return to you the result.

Comment: It works now! Thanks a lot! =) (Sorry for the double post, I had to check it first and I exceeded the 5 minutes to edit the message.