# Using pipenv fails when running as user in Dockerfile

Tags: python, docker

I have a fairly simple Dockerfile, with `python:3.9` as my base image.

```
FROM python:3.9 as builder

WORKDIR /server/
COPY Pipfile Pipfile.lock /server/

RUN pip install pipenv --no-cache-dir \
    && pipenv install --system --deploy

COPY . /server/
```

However I was advised I should not use any commands inside this image as root user, and instead create my own user first.

However when I do this, the `pipenv install` command suddenly fails:
`/bin/sh: 1: pipenv: not found`

I'm struggling to understand why this would fail, and have a difficult time googling, since I have no idea what to even google for at this point.

```
FROM python:3.9 as builder

RUN useradd -ms /bin/bash sorted
USER sorted

WORKDIR /server/
COPY Pipfile Pipfile.lock /server/

RUN pip install pipenv --no-cache-dir \
    && pipenv install --system --deploy

COPY . /server/
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you switch `USER` to a non-root user *before* running `pip`, it's able to figure out that it can't write to the "system" Python directories, and so it instead runs in [user mode](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/user_guide/#user-installs).  This puts both Python packages and Python entry point scripts into a subdirectory of the current user's home directory, which isn't especially well-defined in Docker.  I'd guess that you have a `/.local/bin/pipenv` script inside the image, but that directory isn't on the normal command search `$PATH`.

The typical advice I've heard around Docker is that a container shouldn't *run* as root, but the Dockerfile is relatively trusted and it's okay to have `RUN` commands as root (in a couple of cases this is required).  If you `RUN pip install` as root then the wrapper scripts will go into `/usr/local/bin`, which you can find normally.

```bash
FROM python:3.9 as builder

RUN useradd -r sorted

# still as root
RUN pip install pipenv --no-cache-dir \
    && pipenv install --system --deploy

# only when you go to run the container
USER sorted
CMD ["./main.py"]
```

If you really can't run anything at all as root in the Dockerfile then you need to find the "user" directory.  The [pip documentation](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/user_guide/) has many examples of using `python -m pip` instead of the `pip` wrapper and this will have an extended search path.  You'll also need to run [pipenv](https://pipenv.pypa.io/en/latest/) in its default "user" mode, which will mean wrapping every Python-related invocation in `pipenv run` (also see [How to get pipenv running in docker?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46503947/how-to-get-pipenv-running-in-docker)).

```bash
FROM python:3.9 as builder

RUN useradd -r sorted
USER sorted
ENV PATH=$HOME/.local/bin:$PATH

RUN pip install pipenv --no-cache-dir \
    && pipenv install --deploy

CMD ["pipenv", "run", "./main.py"]
```

The one particular advantage of this setup is around multi-stage builds.  Your Dockerfile uses multi-stage build syntax, and some Python libraries depend on C extensions that have heavy-weight dependencies, but only at build time.  If the build and final images use the same base image then you can `COPY` the entire virtual environment across, which will let you avoid installing large meta-packages like `build-essential` in the final images.  (Note, again, that the Debian `apt-get` package manager *must* run as root.)

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. With your first example, I was able to get my Dockerfile up and running again!